# What will be on the top of this decorative calendar?

Tags: code-golf

Someone gave my wife a decorative calendar consisting of four cubes. Here it is showing today's date (as of the posting of this challenge) on the front:

[image]

When I first saw it, I looked at it from the wrong angle (from directly above) and couldn't figure out why it gave this information:

```
[["February", "January"], [3], [7], ["Monday", "Tuesday"]]
```

Your job is to replicate my error for any date in 2019.

### Challenge

Write a program or function that takes any date from 2019, and outputs what appears on the ***top*** of all the cubes when that date is displayed facing out from the front of the calendar.

Here are all six sides for all the cubes. To display a `6` you just turn the `9` upside down. The `0` is vertically symmetrical, so `0` upside down is still `0`. There might be more than one correct answer for some dates (e.g. any 11th of any month will have more than one way to use the cubes, and the `0` thing) so you can output any correct answer.

[image]

### Rules

1. Standard loopholes forbidden.
2. Input/output format is flexible.
3. The output does have to be in order by cube, but not within a cube. The order must be month cube first, then the two number cubes, followed by the weekday cube. But when a cube has two elements on top, those two elements can be in either order.
4. You can replace `January` to `December` 0-11 or 1-12 if you like.
5. You can replace the days of the week with 0-6 or 1-7 if you like, and you can start the week on either `Sunday` or `Monday` (but you can't start the week on any other day - this is PPGC, not some sort of crazy-town.)
6. This is [code-colf](/questions/tagged/code-colf). Fewest bytes for each language wins.
7. Explanations encouraged.

### Test cases

```
(Tue) 2019-01-29   [[ "July", "August" ], [3], [7], [ "Thursday", "Wednesday" ]]
                   [[ "August", "July" ], [3], [7], [ "Wednesday", "Thursday" ]]

                   etc. since the order within each cube doesn't matter.


(Thu) 2019-07-11   [[ "May", "June" ], [3], [8], [ "Saturday", "Friday" ]]
                   [[ "May", "June" ], [8], [3], [ "Saturday", "Friday" ]]

                   since the two 1 cubes could be either way.

(Sun) 2019-10-27   [[ "January", "February" ], [3], [6], [ "Friday", "Saturday" ]]

(Wed) 2019-05-01   [[ "March", "April" ], [8], [3], [ "Monday", "Tuesday" ]]
                   [[ "March", "April" ], [6], [3], [ "Monday", "Tuesday" ]]
                   [[ "March", "April" ], [9], [3], [ "Monday", "Tuesday" ]]

                   since the 0 cube could have either the 8 side or the 6 side facing up, and the 6 could also be considered a 9.


(Sat) 2019-08-24   [[ "February", "January" ], [8], [5], [ "Sunday" ]]
```

Comment: So... I've been wondering, how is this decorative thing able to show all dates?

Comment: @ErikTheOutgolfer which date is missing?

Comment: Not related to the challenge, but, since I can't ping you over chat, how do you use the two middle cubes? I mean, all 10 digits should be able to be represented.

Comment: The cubes can be used in either order. Let's call the two numeric cubes Top Right and Bottom Left as in the graphic. To get 18 you use 1 from Top Right and 8 from Bottom Left. To get 13 you use 1 from Bottom Left and 3 from Top Right. And so on. 0 1 and 2 have to be on both cubes. The fact that 6 and 9 share the same cube face gives you everything from 01 to 31 which is all that is needed.

Comment: According to the pictures, `27` in `2019-10-27` should go to `36`, not `32`.

Answer (score 5):

## [C (glibc)](https://gcc.gnu.org), <sub><s>327</s> <s>319</s></sub> 286 bytes

```c
#define C strftime(s
#define U(B,E)S[6]=E-1,C+B,99,"%A"+2*!E,S)
S[9],s[99];f(M,D){S[4]=112233107696>>3*M&7;C,9,"%B",S);S[4]^=1;
C+3,9,"%B",S);M=161102>>(D+M*23/9-1-2*(M>2))%7*3&7;U(6,M);U(9,(M^1));
printf("%s/%s %d%d %s/%s\n",
s,s+3,D>29?4:D%10<6?8:3,D>29?8:1070160091>>D%10*3&7,s+6,s+9);}
```

(Some line breaks added for clarity)

`f` takes a month (1–12) and a day (1–31). Prints to stdout. [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##VVFNj4IwEL37K7ps2LQwZNti0FLBrOCxJ@OJxcSoGBNlDcWT8a8vW/AjyyTTmbx5b16bbrzNcV3um@Z9uysO5Q4lSNdVUR9OO6wHT3CJZzAniyzIo7nHIHFnIARY9pflcudtDgsyWGQiB50JkcsCK0jJdZEN84gxzn2f0VEggjj2HfUxkgm02pllZLIlrSImE9f/h6qIBYxRHsc4dZXD/U/hMY87WMWcEHvk@GbNEgegiCkCsFoxQuS5OpR1gS1bf9oa2Vt7i7r2u7RAgzYWaczFdBimNqOTYDoOH8g4NDekLKBUsDhup62DUQQmBZG35rQ@lJig6wCZMC5IpVmOInT1gYIP/JGv7iY7ZvFTIdzRDZdJUyamctO47nNbj5feeWnL42Pktj7KY7mB@oo2nu/llAnPpnzbHSGyAClAKZE9dvstPfD26s6XWmPLeszueLWrL1WJqBzcmt9NcVzvdfMH)

Test cases:

```
2019-01-29: July/August 37 Thursday/Wednesday
2019-07-11: May/June 83 Saturday/Friday
2019-10-27: January/February 36 Friday/Saturday
2019-05-01: March/April 83 Monday/Tuesday
2019-08-24: February/January 85 /Sunday
```

#### Ungolfed

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <time.h>
void f(int M, int D) {
    int month_cube[] = {6,3,0,5,2,7,4,1,4,0,5,1};
    int day_cube[] = {3,3,3,4,5,2,2,6,7,7};
    int week_cube[] = {6,1,5,2,7,4,0}; /* 1=Sun, 7=Sat, 0=none */
    int D1 = D/10, D2 = D%10;
    char s[4][99] = {{0}};
    struct tm t;

    t.tm_mon = month_cube[M-1];
    strftime(s[0], 99, "%B", &t);
    t.tm_mon = month_cube[M-1]^1;
    strftime(s[1], 99, "%B", &t);

    if (D1 >= 3) { /* D = 30, 31 */
        D1 = 4, D2 = 8;
    } else {
        if (D2 <= 5) {
            D1 = 8; /* 012[69]78: 012 -> 8 */
        } else {
            D1 = 3; /* 012345: 012 -> 3 */
        }
        D2 = day_cube[D2];
    }

    int W = (D + M*23/9 - 1 - 2*(M>2)) % 7; /* day of week */
    if (week_cube[W]) {
        t.tm_wday = week_cube[W] - 1;
        strftime(s[2], 99, "%A", &t);
    }
    if (week_cube[W]^1) {
        t.tm_wday = (week_cube[W]^1) - 1;
        strftime(s[3], 99, "%A", &t);
    }

    printf("%s/%s %d%d %s/%s\n", s[0], s[1], D1, D2, s[2], s[3]);
}
```

#### Digit cubes

These are the possibilities for the digits:

```
Cube 1:
0 1 2 3 4 5
3 3 3 4 5 2
5

Cube 2:
0 1 2        6 7 8 9
8 8 8        2 6 7 7
6                2
9
```

The following mapping seems like the best choice for golfing:

```
   01 02 03 04 05 06 07 08 09
   83 83 84 85 82 32 36 37 37

10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19
83 83 83 84 85 82 32 36 37 37

20 21 22 23 24 25 26 27 28 29
83 83 83 84 85 82 32 36 37 37

30 31
48 48
```

#### Cheats

`strftime` is meant to be called with a `struct tm` as input. Instead, I declare `int S[9]` and use `S[4]` as `tm_mon` and `S[6]` as `tm_wday`. This works if the C library uses the same list of struct members as the ISO standard.

`s[99]` is used to store various strings from `strftime`, but making it an `int` array saves a few bytes in indexing.

Answer (score 3):

## JavaScript (ES6), 142 bytes

Takes input as `(year, month, day0, day1)` where \$month\$ is 1-indexed, \$day0\$ is the first digit of the date and \$day1\$ is the second digit.

Returns `(month0, month1, day0, day1, weekDay0, weekDay1)` where week days are 0-indexed with \$0\$ for Sunday. If the second week day is blank, it is set to \$-1\$.

```javascript
(y,m,t,u)=>[M=-~((s='45226276204264')[m--+6]||4*m%2),M+1,t<3?u<6?8:3:s[t-3],u<3?3:s[u-3],D=s[(new Date(y,m,t*10+u).getDay()+6)%7+7],-~D%7||-1]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##XY5Bb4IwGIbv/IrvYmjlK6MFQZ3VC1dPOxIORKvZImJou8WM@ddZ65Jl7tCm7/M@7de35r3Ru/71Yti526vxIEdyxRYNWirX1VayGyFahtlMiFwUuUgykWchrVrGorwehmzaTgTFbcTRrNKNXeWb@TJd6sqwtEbrkA/Wh1LqipzVB5SNUT9TpjyJLI2PypTNldAop5MiKmpkt3JSDAPj9WiUNiDB@dAiGARLQa7hMwDolXbN4W/17PCuO@vupOJTdyRXiCB8Ct1OWn8MaXxp9i@m6Q0RCAn97Y1b1idgbA2euOdp8BUE/gdEJHyBABzBXVvQB1ig5/wB8uRuFo/mzI38b8L8bmZ0/AY)